# Show similarity index of two files in a Git repository

Tags: git

Is it possible to show the similarity index of two files in a Git repository using `git diff`? According to the man pages, `git diff -p` may produce patches with this information *in certain cases*, but the following command for example does not contain the similarity index information:

```
git diff -p --no-index a b
```

Where `a` and `b` are two files known to the repository. Is it possible to let Git calculate and report this similarity index between two existing files in a repository?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, no—or more precisely, not with any existing front-end command.  The only way to get Git to compute a similarity index for two files is to create two *tree* objects in which it seems possible, to Git, that the file was renamed.

We can, however, do just that.  Here's the method:

1. Create a temporary index file name.
2. Add the first file to the temporary index and write out a tree, saving its hash ID.
3. Remove the first file and add the second file; write out a new tree as before.
4. Diff the two trees with `--find-renames=01`.

(Using a rename threshold of `00` does not work: this just disables rename-detection.)

I wrapped this up into a script that is [here](https://github.com/chris3torek/scripts/blob/master/git-similarity) and also appears below.  Place the script somewhere in your `$PATH` (I use `$HOME/scripts/` as a directory containing executable scripts that run on any architecture) and you can run `git similarity a b`.

(This is lightly tested.)

---

```sh
#! /bin/sh
#
# git-similarity: script to compute similarity of two files

. git-sh-setup # for die() etc

TAB=$'\t'

# should probably use OPTIONS_SPEC, but not yet
usage()
{
    echo "usage: git similarity file1 file2"
}

case $# in
2) ;;
*) usage 1>&2; exit 1;;
esac

test -f "$1" || die "cannot find file $1, or not a regular file"
test -f "$2" || die "cannot find file $2, or not a regular file"
test "x$1" != "x$2" || die "file names $1 and $2 are identical"

TF=$(mktemp) || exit 1

trap "rm -f $TF" 0 1 2 3 15
export GIT_INDEX_FILE=$TF

# create a tree holding (just) the argument file
maketree() {
    rm -f $TF
    git add "$1" || exit 1
    git write-tree || exit 1
}

# Use git diff-tree here for repeatibility.  We expect output of
# the form Rnnn$TAB$file1$TAB$file2, but if we get two lines,
# with D and A, we'll just print 000 here.
print_similarity() {
    set $(git diff-tree --name-status --find-renames=01 $1 $2)
    case "$1" in
    R*) echo "${1#R}";;
    *) echo "000";;
    esac
}

h1=$(maketree "$1")
h2=$(maketree "$2")
print_similarity $h1 $h2
```

Comment: Thank you. I am wondering now though whether it is not simpler to just write a script that calculates the ratio between the number of lines added/removed and the overall/maximum(?) number of lines of the input files (which seems to be roughly what Git uses to calculate a similarity index).

Comment: The similarity index isn't line-based though: it uses the internal delta compression code (in a different way than the *actual* delta compression code) after stripping out any carriage returns. It's kind of an odd calculation.

Comment: Ok, I'm convinced :) I'll use your script, thanks!

Comment: I had to add `-r` to the `git diff-tree` command for `git-similarity` to work when called from a sub directory in a repo.

Comment: Ah, right, I only tested it with simple file names.  It would perhaps be better to whack on `maketree()` to allow files outside the Git repository entirely, but that's more complicated. I'll update my script on github, meanwhile.

Comment: Yes, initially I was a bit confused this does not work for files outside of a repo :) I thought about extending the script for this case but I think almost all the time I want to calculate the similarity of files already checked in to a repo. Its useful! A bit slow if you want to calculate the similarity between all combinations of a files in a directory, but maybe that depends also on the size of the 'parent' repo, not sure. Thanks again.